# How do I dynamically update my canvas size (real pixels) when the viewport changes?

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas

I am using using bootstrap4 and placing a `<canvas id='can'>` in a `<div>` (with 0 padding)
CSS: `canvas {height: 200; width 100%;}`. I my js `init()` method, I reset `can.height` and `can.width` to match my  (e.g., `document.getElementById('can').getBoundingClientRect(`)). So real pixels match CSS pixels.

This works well until the user resizes the browser (i.e., changes the viewport).

My question is: **How do I set an event handler to fire when the viewport changes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    //do whatever to set the size
}, false);
```